# Windows 8: How To Use String Resource For Multiple Control Properties

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I am just starting out with Windows 8/RT app development using C#/XAML and am trying to learn about string resources. I've got a string that I would like to use both as button content and as textblock text. In the examples that I've seen, it looks like I would need to define two different strings in my resource file named something like "myButtonString.Content" and "myTextBlockString.Text". Ideally, I'd like to define my string once in the resource file and use it wherever I please. Is there way that I can define a single resource with a name such as "myString" and assign it to both my button content and my textblock text via xaml? If so, how can I do this?

As a point of reference, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965326.aspx) is the resource that I got my initial info from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use Portable Class Library.

1. Localization can be shared between the Windows Phone <-> Windows Store projects
2. It's visible at runtime in xaml editor
3. You'll use it in the same manner at the both platforms.

It's generally easy, just follow [these instructions](http://suchan.cz/2013/09/shared-localization-for-windows-phone-8-and-windows-8-apps-using-pcl/).
One thing to remember - you should create one line resource file in the WS project for the each language. Otherwise VS will not include them from PCL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745650%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to globalizing labels. The same can be used with any UI component. Instead of using whatever.Text="My Button" use whatever.Text=resources.labels.lblMyButton. Your resource files are based on a default resource, for example labels.resx. When the threads culture changes then the appropriate labels_ISO_CULTURE.resx will override whatever is defined in the default.resx.

Take a look at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there a way to access resources.labels.lblMyButton directly from the text property of a textblock in the XAML without having to bind to a viewmodel property? I didn't notice an example of that in the link you provided.

Comment: Here is a link to using ResourceManager  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd882554%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: This looks like exactly what I have done for Windows Phone projects in the past, but is it applicable to Windows 8/RT apps? For example, I don't see a way to mark my .resw file as public as is done in step 2 and I'm not clear as to how I can obtain an instance of my resources file as is done in step 3.

Comment: Look at the top of your resource view the modifier attribute is a drop down list and public is an option.

Comment: That is present in VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone when dealing with a .resx file. However, it is not present in VS 2013 Express for Windows when dealing with a .resw file. The .resw file does not appear to have an associated c# file, so that may be the reason why the drop down is not present.

Comment: Yes, .resw have no code file, this is the reason why PCL is better way to do localization. Because PCL have .resx files inside.